# Jssor slide doesn't work on touch screens going up and down

Tags: jssor

I can swipe going left or right on my phone and iPad; however, I can't swipe going up and down. I would like to know what I can do to making swiping up and down possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please set $DragOrientation to 2.

You know, it's reasonable to enable drag at both horizontal and vertical orientation for desktop.
But it will override touch scroll feature on mobile device. So vertical drag is disabled by default on mobile device.

But if a slider is dedicated for vertical drag ($DragOrientation: 2), it will be enabled then.